# Entity Framework 4 - Include self-related table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, include

I have an self-related table:

```
UnitID    UnitParentID   Name
```

Code to retrieve 1 level  :

```
return contexto.unit
             .Include("unit1")
```

Code to retrieve 2 levels :

```
return contexto.unit
             .Include("unit1.unit1")
```

Code to retrieve 3 levels :

```
return contexto.unit
             .Include("unit1.unit1.unit1")
```

How do I do this for many levels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had that Problem these days and resolved it like this.

You have to load all entites first like:

```
List<unit> myUnits = (from o in ctx.unit
                     .Expand("units")
                      select o).ToList();
```

After that you have to select these units you want to have like:

```
var selectedUnits = myUnits.Where(u => u.Property == x).ToList();
```

This works fine for me! Hope I could help you!

Best regards Julian

Comment: .Expand(...) is a method that worked with me. I couldn't use .Include(...) because it wasn't available to me, since I'm using WCF Data Services. But this will also work with .Include() I think. You just have to use your List that you got from entiyframework and not the parent object.

Comment: Julian, worked well, but I am concerned about the immediate load (.ToList()) of the EF.
Load late does not work .

    `var context = new Context();
            
            List<unit> units =  context.units 
                .Include("unit1").ToList();

            return units 
                .Where(a => a.id_rep == idRep)
                .Where(b => b.id_tipounidade_pai == null);`

Any suggestion?

Comment: No sorry, no suggeestion for that until now. I do it this way and it works. I'd prefer don't doing it this way but haven't found any solution for that. If you find something please tell, would be nice. :)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You don't.

Longer answer: You add an extra column to unit to identify unit's belonging together. 
Then you do something like:

```
var tempResult = myDataContext.unit.Where(x => x.id == id);
return tempResult.FirstOrDefault(); //or some other logik to return the correct 'first' unit.
```